# How to align 2 submit in half panel?

Tags: html, css

This is in php

```
<div class='pnl-aln' style='float:right'>
  <div style:'float: left; width: 50%'>
    <form action = 'Page1.php'>
        <input type='submit' class='btn-scelta' value='ACA'>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div style:'float: right; width: 50%'>
    <form action = 'Page2.php'>
        <input type='submit' class='btn-scelta' value='RUTA'>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

While this is css

```
.pnl-aln{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.btn-scelta{
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-family: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700");
  font-size: 2vw;
  border: solid 3px #000;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

Those two submit are placed in half panel, I've tried many types of code but nothing has worked.
Please help me because I'm getting mad at this and it's at the end of my project :(

Comment: What's your problem I didn't understand ? Why you are using 2 FROM and why you won't use Jquery ?

Comment: @IvanBarayev the problem is that at school they didn't theach us Jquery, so I even don't know a single comand in Jquery..

Comment: Ok understood you, add more detail to your question for get help...

Comment: Biondo, your question is somewhat unclear.  Are you trying to get the 2 forms to be alongside each other, each using half of the available space?

Comment: Problem solved :)
Soon I will start learn Jquery because I heard that is very helpful, thanks anyway for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panel style was mentioned float right , so the form resides on right half screen with 50%
Few syntax errors in divs under panel for tag style:"float:right" which is wrong way and it should  be style="float:right"

codepen -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZmJNG for reference

```
<div class='pnl-aln' style='float:right'>
```

Comment: your like my professor, he looks at the code and finds the error in a second :D
Thanks very much